# Alfresco Mobile Android Error on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, alfresco

I download alfresco android sdk 1.0.1 from this [link](http://www.alfresco.com/cmis/browser?id=workspace://SpacesStore/8e1284fb-26ab-4f91-9666-c24ef915adaf) then I unzip file.

After that I open my eclipse, create new workspace then click FIle -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace -> Root Directory I browse in unzip sdk -> Select All -> Check Copy Projects into workspace -> Finish

Then I Found many error in src directory, for example like this code

```
@Override
public Loader<LoaderResult<PagingResult<ActivityEntry>>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle ba)
{
    if (!hasmore)
    {
        setListShown(false);
    }

    // Case Init & case Reload
    bundle = (ba == null) ? getArguments() : ba;

    ListingContext lc = null, lcorigin = null;

    if (bundle != null)
    {
        lcorigin = (ListingContext) bundle.getSerializable(ARGUMENT_LISTING);
        lc = copyListing(lcorigin);
        loadState = bundle.getInt(LOAD_STATE);
    }
    calculateSkipCount(lc);
    ActivityStreamLoader loader = new ActivityStreamLoader(getActivity(), alfSession);
    loader.setListingContext(lc);
    return loader;
}
```

Error mark on second line (public Loader ...) Eclipse said:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The methode onCreateLoader(int, Bundle) of type ActivityStreamFragment must override a superclass method
- implements android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<org.alfresco.mobile.android.api.asynchronous.LoaderResult<org.alfresco.mobile.android.api.model.PagingResult<org.alfresco.mobile.android.api.model.ActivityEntry>>>.onCreateLoader
```

That I want to know is what should I do to solve this error? Because I want to build alfresco android with that source code..

Note: I using alfresco-android-sdk-1.0.1, Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.2, jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Java 1.5 `(jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p)` to compile your application, you need to upgrade your compiler to 1.6 as some changes were made to the @Override annotation.

> In Java 5, the @Override annotation might be applied only to the
>   methods overriding superclass ones. Since Java 6 you can use the
>   @Override annotation also with the methods that implements the
>   interface ones.

There is also a possibility that you may already have it installed, but not set in eclipse - you can change the compiler version in the project properties : **Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level**.

Sources:

- http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/02/override-differences-in-java-5-and-java-6/
- [build settings](https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/alfresco/mobile/android/sdk/alfresco-mobile-android-sdk/1.0.1/alfresco-mobile-android-sdk-1.0.1.pom) for alfresco states it needs 1.6 to compile (`<maven.compile.source>1.6</maven.compile.source>`)

Comment: then install jdk-6u45-windows-i586 and setting eclipse: window -> preferences -> java -> compiler to 1.6 and it's work. Many thanks shadrxninga.